# itextsharp how to recognize that i have initials box

Tags: itext, digital-signature

I have a file with a 3 editable fields, 2 for digital signature and 1 for initials.

How to find which one is Initial Box? The method `GetBlankSignatureNames`  return 3 fields with the same values , except names and location. Do not see any other differences or property that i can use to find Initials Box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdf specification does not explicitly mention any way to mark a signature field to be for "initials only".

It offers one way, though, to signal this to a specific pdf processor (e.g. Adobe Reader), the signature seed value **AppearanceFilter**:

> **AppearanceFilter** text string *(Optional; PDF 2.0)* A text string naming the appearance that shall be used when signing the signature field. interactive PDF processors may choose to maintain a list of named signature appearances. This text string provides authors with a means of specifying which appearance should be used to sign the signature field.
>
> If the required bit **AppearanceFilter** in **Ff** is set, the appearance shall be available to sign the document and is used.

This value may be used to indicate that a given field shall be signed with an appearance looking like initials.

So you say the three field you got have *the same values except names and locations*, but have you indeed dug down into seed values and compared them?

Other than that you can apply heuristics,  you may check whether the differences you found in *names and locations* offer a hint, e.g. a field name containing "initial" as sub string or a location that is particularly small...